# Fluent Nhibernate and Nhibernate 2.1.0.1003

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Im experiencing some frustration trying to upgrade the nhibernate libraries that Fluent NHibernate uses.

Im also using Nhibernate.Linq and am wanting to use NHibernate.Validator, specifically the ValidationDef class.

Now Nhibernate.Validator is up to using Nhibernate 2.1.0.1003, and when i try to build FluentNhibernate against this verion it get some test errors.

It has to do with SessionFactory configuration and the newish Nhibernate.ByteCode.Castle library.

Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: did you manage to get Linq to work with 2.1? What changes were necessary, i get compile errors. Naively trying to fix them

Comment: hey, yeah i got fluentnhib, linq and validator running on nhib 2.1.0.1003.

I had a couple of compile issue initially, what issues are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think FNH "officially" supports NHibernate 2.1 and probably won't until after it is actually released. However, it's my understanding that it is possible to get it to work. See if [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/bbe26da6967cc247/41cb324f31ebc879?lnk=gst&q=nhibernate+2.1#41cb324f31ebc879) on the FNH groups is helpful.